# List all values in excel range with a condition and date range

Tags: excel

[My excel data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FErhK.png)

I have two conditions to draw the value in another sheet:

1. Customer name
2. Date Range From... To...

---

**Example:**

```
I would like to draw all Campaign number that related to Customer from 01/03/2019 to 21/03/2019.
```

**Expected Result**

```
Choose: Customer A, Date from 01/03/2019 to 20/03/2019 -> CPC1
Choose: Customer A, Date from 01/03/2019 to 21/03/2019 -> CPC1, CPC3
```

[I would like the result like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAEax.png)

Could anyone suggest me what is the formula in excel to achieve this?

Comment: This is difficult to understand. Can you give an example of what you want the results to be?

Comment: and where would you like us to put the results?

Comment: I have added the picture showing how i would like the result to be. if I choose date range and customer like in the screenshot, it will list all Campaign number that related to this customer in column C.

Comment: could anyone help me on this please??